# How to check how much RAM is supported by my Laptop

Tags: laptop, memory

I've been using a HP Pavilion DV 6000 TX laptop for quite some time. It has 1 GB of RAM as of now. 
How can I know if I can add additional RAM to this laptop? I would like to increase the RAM to as close as possible to 3-4GB.

Answer (score 3):

[Kingston](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=31871&mfr=HP%2FCompaq&model=Pavilion+Notebook+dv6000z+Series+%28CTO%29&root=&LinkBack=&Sys=31871-HP%2FCompaq-Pavilion+Notebook+dv6000z+Series+%28CTO%29&distributor=0&submit1=Search) says 2GB - if the manufacturer doesn't say, check either Kingston or Crucial.

Answer (score 2):

according to **[Crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Pavilion%20dv6000t%20Series)** the **HP Pavilion DV 6000 TX** supports 2 GB RAM.

Each of the two memory slot can hold **DDR2 PC2-5300** with a maximum of 1GB per slot.

having said that, these are manufacturer recommendations. i suggest that you check if there is a BIOS update available from HP for your model and then ask at a local computer store to have 4 GB fit into your laptop. yes, they're more expensive than online retailers, but  you better go this router rather than buying 4 GB online only to find out that it doesn't work and no chance of returning the purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Install an app (like Everest on Windows) which offers to you info about the motherboard in your laptop. Then, look out for the MotherBoard specs (dtaasheets, reference in the website of the manufacturer or HP itself), there should be your answer :)